# List of Lotus Notes versions

Tags: lotus-notes, ibm-domino

How to get list of Lotus Notes versions connected to Lotus Domino server?
Is that data available in any database file on a server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [article](http://www.eknori.de/2008-02-02/domino-directory-people-by-client-version/) describes how to see what clients connected to the domino server. Or you can try [this](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/NotesTips.htm#trackusers).